# How to tell a method has a varargs argument using reflection?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Here is a sample code

```
package org.example;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class TestRef {

        public void testA(String ... a) {
                for (String i : a) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){

                Class testRefClass = TestRef.class;

                for (Method m: testRefClass.getMethods()) {
                        if (m.getName() == "testA") {
                                System.out.println(m);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

The output is

```
public void org.example.TestRef.testA(java.lang.String[])
```

So the signature of the method is reported to take a array of String.

Is there any mean in the reflection library I can tell that the method is **originally** declared to take a varargs?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is there any mean in the reflection library I can tell that the method is originally declared to take a varargs?

Yup.  [`java.lang.reflect.Method.isVarArgs()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#isVarArgs()).

However, this is only of use if you are trying to assemble and display method signatures in human readable form.  If you need to invoke a varargs method using reflection, you will have to assemble the varargs arguments into an array-typed argument.

Comment: It should also be noted that method.getModifiers() will have the Modifier.TRANSIENT bit set for a varargs method.

Comment: @ILMTitan - I don't see why that is worth noting.  The `transient` modifier is not meaningful for a method.  The bit is only set because the corresponding classfile flag bit is used for different things in different contexts; i.e. the TRANSIENT and VARARGS bits are the same bit.

Answer (score 1):

there is really no difference

```
static public void main(String[]  args)
static public void main(String... args)
```

actually the ... notation was introduced very late in the process of adding vararg in java. James Gosling proposed it, he thinks it's cuter. Before that, the same [] denotes the vararg.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? It seems that the difference is much more profound than aesthetics.

Comment: The difference exists only at the compiler level and when using reflection to collect information about java types. At runtime (in bytecode), varargs methods look like the array version and all callers implicitly create an array before invoking the method (code for which is generated at compile-time).