# Javadoc API: How far are varargs supported?

Tags: java, javadoc, variadic-functions

I want to write my custom doclet. I don't want to read some existing
javadoc that is made with the standard doclet.

I am having problems to figure out how I can query the Javadoc API
whether a formal parameter is a varargs paramter. For example if
I have the following method:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
}
```

How can I determine that the formal parameter args is varargs? I
have looked into [com.sun.javadoc.Type](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/javadoc/Type.html). But was not able to figure
out how to access the information.

Bye

P.S.: Reflection doesn't help, since reflection is not available inside
a doclet I guess. In a doclet you have for example the [MethodDoc](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/javadoc/MethodDoc.html) reflected
class, whereas in reflection you have the Method class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell a method has a varargs argument using reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042050/how-to-tell-a-method-has-a-varargs-argument-using-reflection)

Comment: @CookieMonster You can start a bounty to attract more attention to your questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it, its an attribute of the MethodDoc super class:

```
public interface ExecutableMemberDoc {

    public boolean isVarArgs();
    // Return true if this method was declared to 
    // take a variable number of arguments.

}
```

To make it work you have to put the following static (sic!)
method and return value into your doclet class:

```
public static LanguageVersion languageVersion() {
    return LanguageVersion.JAVA_1_5;
}
```

Oki Doki. Case closed.

Comment: I would add a link to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/ExecutableMemberDoc.html

Answer (score -1):

I think javadoc API clearly shows if argument is varargs.

Check below APi

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

It has a method as given below with varargs

format(Locale l, String format, **Object... args**)

Comment: I want to write my custom doclet. I don't want to read some existing
javadoc that is made with the standard doclet.